# Wordpress custom post not showing featured

Tags: php, wordpress

I have come across a strange problem when creating a new wordpress theme. So maybe because I have been at this all day but need to see if anyone can spot my error or see what is the problem.

I am trying to display 'featured' posts as per the name of the category and show only the one if this has been checked in the wp-admin section. Yet I am defining this within the code but it shows the latest post instead regardless of it being featured or not.

```
<?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'category_mame' => 'featured',
                'posts_per_page' => 1
            );

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="push_2 grid_10 omega clearfix">
                <article>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                </article>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change first this

```
'category_mame' => 'featured',
```

to

```
'category_name' => 'featured', // name not mame
```

---

**[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters)** are the built-in status parameters of Wordpress.

I don't know if this is exactly the thing you are searching for but you can Query your post after status if you add `post_status` to the `$args`-array:

```
 $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'category_mame' => 'featured',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',   //or 'draft', 'trash', 'pending', ... (see the link above)

        );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh my, that is highly embarrassing, the typo was the issue ('mame'). but thank you for the additional information also.